# Unable to deploy WAR file to Websphere using IBM Rational Application Developer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ibm-rad, java-war

I am using the IBM RAD IDE and building a dynamic web project.  When I build the project and attempt to add it to the server by selecting 'add or remove projects' I get the response that there are no projects to add or remove.

Does this mean I will have to create a EAR file (J2EE Project) and add my web project to it in order to deploy to the local WAS?  Might I be missing some essential configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAS requires EAR files, this is not a RAD issue.

Actually there is a work-around that I got from http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/07/cant-deploy-war-on-websphere-6.html but have not tried

Create your WAR.
In your WEB-INF\web.xml. WebSphere validates this against the schema for the web.xml and is not flexible. Add this detail to you opening  node in your web.xml and make sure it is valid according to the schema:

```
<web-app version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"   
xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

You might just want to package your WAR in an EAR which is what everybody does.

Answer (score 0):

From my **very limited** RAD experience, you will indeed need an EAR to deploy. Its pretty painless to do... Are you having a particular problem deploying?

Comment: No - I've done the EAR file and deployed it before, however this time the project does not call for an EAR file and I'd rather just use a simple WAR file.  Most java web servers allow you to drop in a WAR file and it will deploy - I suppose IBM's RAD requires an EAR